# Rough calculation in conclusion section

Tags: thesis

In my conclusion, I imagine what my results could imply for future developments. I want to emphasize my argument with a rough calculation. Is this allowed in a conclusion section?

Comment: There are no universal rules as to what is or isn't "allowed" in a thesis or any section thereof.  You should consult with your advisor and/or committee as to whether what you have in mind is a good idea, as they are the one(s) who will ultimately decide if your thesis is acceptable.

Comment: I'd put it in the Discussion, and in the Conclusions just comment on it/wrap up the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "rules". The only rule is that you should use the best arguments to explain the science behind your work, and its impact. If a rough calculation is what explains the argument best, then that's an entirely reasonable approach:

> The methods we have discussed in the main part of this work have shown that with a proper formulation, optimization algorithms can lower the energy consumption of a large chemical plant by 0.5%. This may not sound like very much, but it is worth keeping in mind that such plants can have electricity costs of more than $100M per year. As a consequence, just the improvements outlined herein can lead to savings of at least half a million dollars per year. This kind of calculation shows the practical impact of the methods we have introduced herein, and clearly suggest that it is worth investigating even better formulations than the ones here.

Answer (score 2):

Not best practice.  You would be better off having that in a section of the Discussion (at the end of the Discussion) with at least a paragraph of explication.  You can use an identifying subheader ("future developments", "economic implications", etc. within Discussion).

Then in the Conclusion, I would stick to more of the traditional method which is to restate the main results. At that point, you summarize all your findings.  And then give a single sentence about the implications.

I think this is better than opening a segue within the Conclusion.

Comment: Shoot.  My advice was for a paper.  I think for a thesis, things are a bit looser.  And it may not fit your structure to have a whole para on future developments within a regular chapter.